# batch cuting mp4 files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode a few seconds of the mp4 files with a batch.
I get the failure "output file #0 does not contain any stream"
here is the code:

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg "%%a" -ss 0 -t 5 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "neu\%%~na.mp4"
pause

First I want to test the batch - encoding only the first 5 seconds of the file.

What can I do?

thanks for your help!!

Comment: this is working: for %%f in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -ss 5 -c:v copy -c:a copy "geschnitten\%%~nf.mp4"

Comment: You can answer your own question by clicking the button below. Please note that when asking ffmpeg questions, you should always include the full, uncut command-line output as well. And when scripting, it's useful to also show the command that was really called, not just the script itself.